# Matching Nodes that have Array properties containing specific values

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have node of type User which has an array property called 'emails' that contains an array of emails (strings).  I am trying to write a cypher query that can be used to look up nodes that match a specific email address (in other words - given an email address, I want to look up all nodes that contain that email address within their 'emails' property.

```
MATCH(u:User) WHERE 'abc@gmail.com' IN u.emails RETURN u;
```

However, the above query returns nothing.  I have confirmed that I do have a node that contains the property, see below:

```
u

id  ed2ac321-60e3-4765-95b6-b097726454bf
emails  ["abc@gmail.com"]
```

Not sure what I'm missing here.

EDIT: I found the issue, thanks to the question posted by stdob.  I was creating the array in correctly - I was using quotes like this:

```
CREATE (u:User {id: 'ed2ac321-60e3-4765-95b6-b097726454bf', emails: '["abc@gmail.com"]'}) RETURN u;
```

Output:
    u
    emails  ["abc@gmail.com"]
    id  ed2ac321-60e3-4765-95b6-b097726454bf

This internally was creating a simple string property called emails, not an array.  To fix this, I removed the quotes:

```
CREATE (u:User {id: 'ed2ac321-60e3-4765-95b6-b097726454bf', emails: ["abc@gmail.com"]}) RETURN u;
```

Output:
    u
    emails  [abc@gmail.com]
    id  ed2ac321-60e3-4765-95b6-b097726454bf

There's a subtle difference in the way the neo4j web interface displays the output of the above two statements, but worth a lot!

Comment: Show how you add a node `User`.

Comment: Your question prompted me to check, and I believe I found the issue.  I was enclosing the array within quotes ('), and so the emails property was actually being stored as a string literal not as an array after all!  Thanks for your insight!

Comment: Just to note, with this model, you won't be able to take advantage of indexes, so this will always use a label scan across all :User nodes' emails lists, which won't scale as you increase :User nodes. You might try remodeling this using :Email nodes, with patterns like (:User)-[:HasEmail]->(:Email). If you have an index on :Email(email), then you can do a fast lookup of an email, and find the :User connected with it.